# Apply a threshold on a Pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, time-series

I have a Daframe that looks like this

```
In [52]: f
Out[52]:
Date
2015-02-23 12:00:00    0.172517
2015-02-23 13:00:00    0.172414
2015-02-23 14:00:00    0.172516
2015-02-23 15:00:00    0.173261
2015-02-23 16:00:00    0.172921
2015-02-23 17:00:00    0.172371
2015-02-23 18:00:00    0.176374
2015-02-23 19:00:00    0.177480
    ...
```

and I want to apply a threshold to the series so that is the values go below it I would just substitute the threshold's value to the actual one.

I am trying to definte a boolean dataframe like

Bool = f > Threshold

but I am not sure how to go on. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IIUC then the following should work:

```
f[f> Threshold] = some_val
```

Or you can use [`clip_upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip_upper.html):

```
f = f.clip_upper(Threshold)
```

This will limit the upper values to your threshold value

```
In [147]:
df[df['val'] > 0.175] = 0.175
df

Out[147]:
                          val
Date                         
2015-02-23 12:00:00  0.172517
2015-02-23 13:00:00  0.172414
2015-02-23 14:00:00  0.172516
2015-02-23 15:00:00  0.173261
2015-02-23 16:00:00  0.172921
2015-02-23 17:00:00  0.172371
2015-02-23 18:00:00  0.175000
2015-02-23 19:00:00  0.175000

In [149]:    
df['val'].clip_upper(0.175)

Out[149]:
Date
2015-02-23 12:00:00    0.172517
2015-02-23 13:00:00    0.172414
2015-02-23 14:00:00    0.172516
2015-02-23 15:00:00    0.173261
2015-02-23 16:00:00    0.172921
2015-02-23 17:00:00    0.172371
2015-02-23 18:00:00    0.175000
2015-02-23 19:00:00    0.175000
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: If you have more than one column in your DataFrame this will overwrite them all. So in that case I think you would want to do `df['val'][df['val'] > 0.175] = 0.175`. Though you might also want to split that over two lines to make it easier to eyeball later.

Comment: Updated link to clip method doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html.